# L2 cache bandwidth on Sandy Bridge CPUs

Tags: performance, x86, cpu-cache

tl;dr: what's the established L2 cache bandwidth on Sandy Bridge CPUs for simultaneous sequential reads and writes?

---

I'm trying to estimate the absolute baseline timing of an algorithm of mine on some test data. On that data, it boils down to repeatedly reading around 160 KB of sequential data (so it doesn't fit L1) all while computing and writing back a new block of 160 KB. All that happens on a single core, and multithreading is not involved. A partial sum might be a good approximation to what I'm doing.

I was able to find a few different sources that imply the approximate range of bandwidths to be within 30-100 GB/s. In particular:

- [Agner Fog's manual](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) (p. 132) plus some careful calculations, assuming that I'm able to do two reads per cycle (since I'm expecting the CPU to read whole 64-byte cache lines, so bits 4-6 of the address will be different).
- [This](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/480004) thread.
- A blog post that I cannot easily find now that was analysing raw read bandwidth and got around 100 GB/s, but it was (a) for Skylake and (b) without simultaneous writes.

Anyway, what would be a reasonable estimate in this case?

Comment: [This article, page 7, §5.1](https://tu-dresden.de/zih/forschung/ressourcen/dateien/abgeschlossene-projekte/benchit/2014_MSPC_authors_version.pdf?lang=en) says that the bandwidth of the L2 cache on Sandy Bridge is approximately  46.8 GB/s.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/480004

Comment: Thanks! Can it affect the performance of the cache that I'm also doing writes at the same time?

Comment: I have no idea.  :)